# How to use if-else in html

Tags: php, css, asp.net, html

I want to use selected option with condition. if $type is room then bed will be selected and if it is bathroom then toilet will be selected. what is wrong with this code. how to correct it????

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      $type="bathroom";
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
      <select name="bedtype">
      <% if($type=="bathroom"){ %>
       <option value="room">BED</option>
       <option value="bathroom" selected>TOILET</option>
      <% } else { %>
       <option value="room" selected>BED</option>
       <option value="bathroom" >TOILET</option>
      <% } %>
      </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like that, but remember to turn on [error handling](http://www.sitepoint.com/error-handling-in-php/) - Your code looks correct assuming your are serving this from a web server and it is [rendered as PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

Comment: output shows all the four options. condition is not working

Comment: View source. I am guessing you will see `<% if($type=="bathroom"){ %>
       <option value="room">BED</option>
       <option value="bathroom" selected>TOILET</option>
      <% } else { %>
       <option value="room" selected>BED</option>
       <option value="bathroom" >TOILET</option>
      <% } %>` - e.g. all the PHP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing ASP and PHP tags.

While ASP tags were allowed in PHP 5, as of PHP 7, they have been **deprecated** and **removed**. You should switch to strictly `<?php` `?>` and `<?=` `?>`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

You also have `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` wrong.

Ternary conditionals would simplify the code greatly. They are in the form  `if true statement ? do truth : do falsehood`. Providing an `echo` statement before the ternary conditional would echo out the true or false result.

```
<html>
<body>
  <?php $type = "bathroom"; ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="bedtype">
      <option value="room" <?php echo $type == "room" ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>BED</option>
      <option value="bathroom" <?php echo $type == "bathroom" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>TOILET</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: >BED is selected using this code.

Comment: That doesn't make sense unless it's somehow the HTML selected not working.

Comment: Try the code again, this works for me in Apache server.

Comment: <option value="bathroom" selected>TOILET</option> is selecting Toilet

Comment: That is correct based on the PHP logic. What do you mean?

Comment: Thank you sir. it is working now

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct in PHP < 7.0.

You use *optional* ASP tags ( `<% (...) %>` ) to embed PHP code.

To activate it, you have to modify your *php.ini* file turning this line:

```
asp_tags = Off
```

in:

```
asp_tags = On
```

**Please note** that ASP tags are rarely used and **completely removed** on PHP 7.0.

To avoid future incompatibility issue, **use standard php tags** `<?php (...) ?>`

As alternative, to **echo** something, you can use short tags `<?= (...) ?>`.

So, this:

```
<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>
```

is the same as:

```
<?= 'Hello World'; ?>
```

or (you can omit closing semicolon):

```
<?= 'Hello World' ?>
```

For the records, there is another short-tag style ( `<? (...) ?>` ) that must be enabled in *php.ini*. However, the use of this short-tag is discouraged and substantially abandoned (this style is primary used to identify XML).